# What is the difference between adjectives "different" and "differing"

Tags: adjectives, word-difference

Do "different" and "differing" mean the same thing? Here are some sentences they were used in:

> 1. "Bill and Mike have different views."
> 2. "Bill and Mike have differing views."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say **different views** simply means that their views are not the same while **differing views** suggests the idea that their views are **opposing**, **disagreeing** or maybe even **conflicting**.

In other words, the first example tells you that their views are not similar with regard to a particular issue whereas the second example gives the notion that the situation is much more problematic because of the two guys' views that are in conflict with each other over a particular matter. I think that's the simplest way to describe the difference between these two words that you can possibly come up with.